# Compiled LinQ queries

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I'd like to see a basic and clear example of how to compile a LinQ to SQL query. I've googled about it, and even though there are a couple of implementation examples, usually blog posters emphasize on the time response difference between compiled and non-compiled queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ To SQL Compiled Queries basically allow that the translation of LinqToSQL query to  plain SQL, happen only once at compile time so the query can be re-used without performing any translation.

They are represented as static [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx) delegates, receiving a DataContext instance and parameters that will be used in the query:

```
public static Func<MyDataContext, string, IQueryable<Entity>>
    TestQuery =
        CompiledQuery.Compile((MyDataContext ctx, string param) =>
            from e in ctx.Entities where e.Field == param select e);
```

An usual practice is that compiled queries can be stored as static members on a partial class that extends the DataContext generated class.

Answer (score 0):

There is one in this question: [CompiledQuery vs. Plain Linq SQL Generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701946/compiledquery-vs-plain-linq-sql-generation/702066#702066)